# log4j logging to two different files with one Logger only

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have read though all post here and though my question repeats the one of others, non of the answers really anwers mine:

I have quite a large project with a logger in almost every class. I wont to keep using only this one Logger and I want it to to create
- a log file with INFO and ERROR
- a separate log file with ERROR only

This is the code is use to log:

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestLogger.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    log.debug("debug");
    log.info("info");
    log.error("error");

}
```

and this is how I thought I cound configure it, leaving out the layout stuff.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
log4j.logger.errors = ERROR, stdout, file, file2

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

...

```
log4j.appender.file=metaobjects.io.CustomFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=c:/temp/execution%timestamp/test.log
```

...

```
log4j.appender.file2=metaobjects.io.CustomFileAppender
log4j.appender.file2.File=c:/temp/execution%timestamp/error.log
```

Is there any way to get what I want or do I need two Logger objects in every class?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create multiple appenders with a different threshold.

Keep in mind `debug` will consume `error` and would consume `info` logging.

try to look into this tutorial
https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/

Comment: I do have different appenders, file and file2, but only the first acutally creates a log file.